# Selecting only one result from looping td with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have td on `html/php` table that searches all documents with filename matching with same rows number identifier.

One td may show multiple document names, if they are named something like `A12345` and `A12345_1`. This td looks like following:

```
<td>
   <?php if (!empty($numero)){
      foreach($dokumentit as $dokumentti) {
         echo "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>
         <a class='dokumentti' href='$dokumentti'>" .basename($dokumentti). "</a>";
      } 
    } ?>
</td>
```

I want to be able to delete the document by clicking the `<i class='fas fa-times'></i>`, and for this I use jQuery code:

```
$('.fa-times').click(function(){
    var dokumentti = $(this).parent().find('.dokumentti').text();
    alert (dokumentti);
});
```

This works for td's with only one document attached, but if td has multiple documents it shows them all, and I'm trying to make it so it would always only show the document name where you clicked the `<i class='fas fa-times'></i>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `$(this).next('.dokumentti').text();`

Comment: @Swati this is it! Thank you for super quick answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to acces the sibling link ,

your code should look like

```
$('.fa-times').click(function(){
    var dokumentti = $(this).next('.dokumentti').text();
    alert (dokumentti);
});
```

here is snippet example :

```js
$('.fa-times').click(function(){
    var dokumentti = $(this).next('.dokumentti').text();
    alert (dokumentti);
});
```

```css
.dokumentti {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<i class='fas fa-times'>icon</i>
<a class='dokumentti' href='#dokumentti'> Doc 1</a>

<i class='fas fa-times'>icon</i>
<a class='dokumentti' href='#dokumentti'> Doc 2</a>

<i class='fas fa-times'>icon</i>
<a class='dokumentti' href='#dokumentti'> Doc 3</a>

<i class='fas fa-times'>icon</i>
<a class='dokumentti' href='#dokumentti'> Doc 4</a>
</div>
```